# Reconnect a disconnected dataset?

Tags: vb.net

I'm using a disconnected Dataset and I've tried several methods to reapply a connection to SQL to pass back my updates.

```
Public Function PassBackFilledDataSet(ByVal dsUpdated As DataSet, _
                                      ByVal queryString As String)

    Dim dsData As New DataSet
    Dim strRowCount As String

    Using connection As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString())
        Using adapter As New SqlDataAdapter() With {.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand(queryString, connection)}
            adapter.Fill(dsData)
            dsData = dsUpdated.Copy

            strRowCount = dsData.Tables(0).Rows.Count
            MsgBox("dsData" & strRowCount)

            ' adapter.Update(dsData.Tables(0))
            dsData.Tables(0).AcceptChanges()
            adapter.Update(dsData.Tables(0))

        End Using

    End Using
End Function
```

But I can't quite figure out why the SQL Side is not updating but the disconnected dataset is.

Any pointers would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you do `adapter.Update(dsUpdated.Tables(0))` ?

Comment: is this not the samething ? adapter.Update(dsData.Tables(0))

Comment: `DbDataAdapter.Update` executes the correct command (INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE) based on the `RowState` of each data row in the table, and `DataTable.AcceptChanges` will mark all rows as `RowState.Unchanged`, thus `DbDataAdapter.Update` does nothing. If your `dsUpdated.Tables(0)` keeps the `RowState` correctly, the result will be different.

Comment: And also, I missed the important point, your `adapter` is missing `UpdateCommand`, `InsertCommand` and `DeleteCommand`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33y2221y.aspx . Assuming your table in your DB(SQL Server) has primary key and your `queryString` includes the key column, the easiest way to generate those automatically is to do `Dim cb As New SqlCommandBuilder(adapter)` before `adapter.Update(dsUpdated.Tables(0))`.

Comment: Thanks Ripple for making this clearer. I can see now that I'm not carrying out the update/insert as you've mentioned.
Will have ago with this again later and let you know how I get on.
:)